# Multi Conditionals (OR, AND) in addAttributeToFilter

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, collection

I am trying to to achieve some thing like

```
SELCT * FROM xyz WHERE ( open_date >= $fromDate AND open_date<= $toDate = ) OR (closed_to_date >= $fromDate AND closed_to_date<= $toDate =)
```

What I am doing is,

```
$fromDate = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date("Y-m-d");
$toDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+2 week"));

        $addressCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter(
                array(
                    array('attribute' => 'open_date', 'gteq' => $fromDate),
                    array('attribute' => 'closed_to_date', 'gteq' => $fromDate),
                )
        );

        $addressCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter(
                array(
                    array('attribute' => 'open_date', 'lteq' => $toDate),
                    array('attribute' => 'closed_to_date', 'lteq' => $toDate),
                )
        );
```

sql query for above magento query is

```
(string) SELECT `e`.*, `at_open_date`.`value` AS `open_date`, `at_closed_to_date`.`value` AS `closed_to_date` FROM `customer_address_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `customer_address_entity_datetime` AS `at_open_date` ON (`at_open_date`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_open_date`.`attribute_id` = '553')
 INNER JOIN `customer_address_entity_datetime` AS `at_closed_to_date` ON (`at_closed_to_date`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_closed_to_date`.`attribute_id` = '384') WHERE (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '2') AND ((at_open_date.value >= '2017-01-19 00:00:00') OR (at_closed_to_date.value >= '2017-01-19 00:00:00')) AND ((at_open_date.value <= '2017-02-02 00:00:00') OR (at_closed_to_date.value <= '2017-02-02 00:00:00'))
```

But what I want is

```
SELECT `e`.*, `at_open_date`.`value` AS `open_date`, `at_closed_to_date`.`value` AS `closed_to_date` FROM `customer_address_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `customer_address_entity_datetime` AS `at_open_date` ON (`at_open_date`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_open_date`.`attribute_id` = '553')
 INNER JOIN `customer_address_entity_datetime` AS `at_closed_to_date` ON (`at_closed_to_date`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_closed_to_date`.`attribute_id` = '384') WHERE (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '2') AND ((at_open_date.value >= '2017-01-19 00:00:00') AND (at_open_date.value <= '2017-02-02 00:00:00')) OR ((at_closed_to_date.value >= '2017-01-19 00:00:00') AND (at_closed_to_date.value <= '2017-02-02 00:00:00'))
```

For more clarification, want to change condition

From

```
AND ((at_open_date.value >= '2017-01-19 00:00:00') OR (at_closed_to_date.value >= '2017-01-19 00:00:00')) AND ((at_open_date.value <= '2017-02-02 00:00:00') OR (at_closed_to_date.value <= '2017-02-02 00:00:00'))
```

To

```
AND ((at_open_date.value >= '2017-01-19 00:00:00') AND (at_open_date.value <= '2017-02-02 00:00:00')) OR ((at_closed_to_date.value >= '2017-01-19 00:00:00') AND (at_closed_to_date.value <= '2017-02-02 00:00:00'))
```

**Update:-1**
Came with a solution, but not a magento way.

```
$addressCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/address_collection');
$addressCollection1 = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/address_collection');

$addressCollection->addAttributeToFilter('open_date', array('gteq' => $fromDate));
$ids1 = $addressCollection->addAttributeToFilter('open_date', array('lteq' => $toDate))->getAllIds();

$addressCollection1->addAttributeToFilter('closed_to_date', array('gteq' => $fromDate));
$ids2 = $addressCollection1->addAttributeToFilter('closed_to_date', array('lteq' => $toDate))->getAllIds();

$result = array_merge($ids1, $ids2);
$final_result = array_unique($result);
```

Any suggestion to improve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
$addressCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter(
                    array('open_date', array('lteq' => $toDate))
        )
        ->addAttributeToFilter(
                    array('closed_to_date', array('gteq' => $fromDate))
        );
```

Comment: is it a valid query?. Because it is not working.

Comment: this is an example. For AND condition, you need to write addfieldToFilter like above in my answer.

Comment: I know this, here query will be "where open_date <=$toDate AND  closed_to_date <=$fromDate", but it is not working any way.

Comment: fromDate also you want less than or greater than. What query this is returning because this should work for your condition

Answer (score 2):

```
$addressCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter(
                    array('open_date', array('gteq' => $fromDate))
        )
        ->addAttributeToFilter(
                    array('closed_to_date', array('lteq' => $toDate))
        );
```

Comment: is it a valid query?. Because it is not working.

Comment: Yes, if  it is an attribute,  you could use addAttributeToFilter else you can use addFieldToFilter